# angular 2 directive with bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm trying to make a simple list group in angular 2 using bootstrap, I place  inside **item.component.ts** and the ul inside **list.components.ts** but I can't figure out how to remove the component directive in angular 2.

```
//list.component.ts
<ul class="list-group">
  <my-list *ngFor....> //how to remove this from the view
    //item.component.ts
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    etc.
  </my-list>
</ul>
```

I dont want to use ng2-bootstrap, and as long as  directive is rendered in the browser, my list-group is not working correctly!

I looked in the previous questions, but couldn't find any good answers how to make this work? How is people solving this problem, I know angular1 had replace:true to handle these issues, but not anymore in angular2.

*1. Should I add "css" on my **my-list** so it behave like **li** and surrender it around **div** instead? But then I have to do this on every bootstrap component I need to use!*

*2. Should I stop using **item.component.ts** and keep everything in the **list.component.ts** to fix this issue?*

Comment: What do you want instead of "<my-list ..."?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier He want to remove it and only have the list items.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I don't think that it's possible. That said, you can leverage a selector on an attribute to apply components... See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support in Angular2 for the `replace: true` feature like in Angular 1.

You could leverage an attribute in the selector to attach the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-component]'
  (...)
})
```

and use it this way:

```
<div my-component>
  <tr>...</tr>
</div>
```

Comment: I have seen this answer on other questions, but I can't see how I should use this?

The purpose of the **item.component.ts** is I can add the **li** inside it. 

Selector attribute only allow me to manipulate the element attributes?

Comment: Please delete your post since it make other people think it works :)